# How to compute all unique permutations and keep the same positive adjacent elements always adjacent?

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I have a list or a vector `V` of `n` nonnegative integers. There are some positive integers that are equal and adjacent, say `V=[2, 3, 3, 0, 0]`. (I do not care about the zero integer.)

I would like to find all *unique* permutations of `V` such that all the same and positive integers remain adjacent. How to write an algorithm for this? (For an implementation, you can choose Python or Matlab or any other language.)

Under Matlab and for the example of `V=[2, 3, 3, 0, 0]`, I get all the unique permuations as follows:

```
V = [2, 3, 3, 0, 0];
unique(perms([2, 3, 3, 0, 0]), 'rows')
```

and I get:

```
 0     0     2     3     3
 0     0     3     2     3
 0     0     3     3     2
 0     2     0     3     3
 0     2     3     0     3
 0     2     3     3     0
 0     3     0     2     3
 0     3     0     3     2
 0     3     2     0     3
 0     3     2     3     0
 0     3     3     0     2
 0     3     3     2     0
 2     0     0     3     3
 2     0     3     0     3
 2     0     3     3     0
 2     3     0     0     3
 2     3     0     3     0
 2     3     3     0     0
 3     0     0     2     3
 3     0     0     3     2
 3     0     2     0     3
 3     0     2     3     0
 3     0     3     0     2
 3     0     3     2     0
 3     2     0     0     3
 3     2     0     3     0
 3     2     3     0     0
 3     3     0     0     2
 3     3     0     2     0
 3     3     2     0     0
```

As you may know, I get `30` such permutations. Among these `30`, there are `18` that do not respect the constraint of adjacency. For example, `[3, 2, 3, 0, 0]` can not be in the final result because `3` is no longer adjacent to `3`. Finally, all unique permutations can be given by:

```
 0     0     2     3     3
 0     0     3     3     2
 0     2     0     3     3
 0     2     3     3     0
 0     3     3     0     2
 0     3     3     2     0
 2     0     0     3     3
 2     0     3     3     0
 2     3     3     0     0
 3     3     0     0     2
 3     3     0     2     0
 3     3     2     0     0
```

The first idea (and the simplest) that came to my mind is to generate all unique permutations like so and then, for each one, verify the constraint. But is there any other efficient algorithm?

Comment: Do you want all the positive numbers to be together or only the positive numbers that are the same to be together?

Comment: I want all positive numbers that are the same and adjacent to be together (stay adjacent).

Comment: Think of each "run" of adjacent elements as a single element, then use any standard permutation algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- We can first compress the given array so that there is just one entry for every positive number, while keeping a count of how many times each number occurred (the zeroes should be left as is).
- Generate the permutations of the compressed array.
- Decompress each of the permutation and retain only the unique ones.

### To Compress

```
def compress(arr):
    counts = {}
    compressed = []
    curr_ele = arr[0]
    count_ele = 0
    for ele in arr:
        if ele != curr_ele or ele == 0:
            counts[curr_ele] = count_ele
            compressed.append(curr_ele)
            count_ele = 1
            curr_ele = ele
        else:
            count_ele += 1
    counts[curr_ele] = count_ele
    compressed.append(curr_ele)
    return compressed, counts
```

### To Uncompress

```
def uncompress(arr, counts):
    res = []
    for ele in arr:
        if ele == 0:
            res.append(0)
            continue
        num_reps = counts[ele]
        for _ in range(num_reps):
            res.append(ele)
    return res
```

### Putting it together: Compress, Permute, Uncompress and Retain Unique

```
import itertools
ip = [2, 3, 3, 0, 0]
ip_compressed, counts = compress(ip)
set([tuple(uncompress(perm, counts)) for perm in itertools.permutations(ip_compressed)])
```

### Result:

```
{(0, 0, 2, 3, 3),
 (0, 0, 3, 3, 2),
 (0, 2, 0, 3, 3),
 (0, 2, 3, 3, 0),
 (0, 3, 3, 0, 2),
 (0, 3, 3, 2, 0),
 (2, 0, 0, 3, 3),
 (2, 0, 3, 3, 0),
 (2, 3, 3, 0, 0),
 (3, 3, 0, 0, 2),
 (3, 3, 0, 2, 0),
 (3, 3, 2, 0, 0)}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple algorithm is:

1.traverse the initial table and make another table with two rows like:

```
input: V = [2, 3, 3, 0, 0];

new array: V2 = |2,3,0|
                |1,2,2|
```

As you can see V2 comes from V keeping one time the elements and in second row counting how many times we have seen them.

2. Now generate all permutations of columns

And for every result e.g:

```
V2 = |3,2,0|
     |2,1,2|
```

you have kept how many times the elements appear.